# Angular: Button does not produce click event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a couple of mat-tab in a mat-tab-group. After creating the 3rd mat-tab, I noticed that the download button (button3) embedded in a mat-list-item does not produce a click event. I added additional buttons 1 and 2 to different places and they both work fine.

```
<mat-tab>
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <mat-icon class="tab-icon">auto_awesome_motion</mat-icon>
      Transitions
  </ng-template>
  <button mat-button (click)="foobar()">button1</button>
  <mat-list style="max-width: 800px;">
      <button mat-button (click)="foobar()">button2</button>
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let t of transitions; let i = index"
          [class.transition-list-even]="i % 2 === 0"
          [class.transition-list-odd]="i % 2 != 0">
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>auto_awesome_motion</mat-icon>
          <div mat-line fxFlex="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
              <div fxLayout="column">
                  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="5px">
                      <span>{{ t.from?.name }}</span>
                      <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon>
                      <span>{{ t.to?.name }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <span class="transition-sub">Transition</span>
              </div>
              <button mat-button (click)="foobar()">button3</button>
          </div>
      </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</mat-tab>
```

Clicking the non-working button (button 3) absolutely nothing happens. Nothing in the console, no network activity, nothing. I have no idea how to debug this further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a CSS problem: you are overlaping some elements as mat-icon and span to the button(with inspect elements you can locate the problem). I can't reproduce the problem correctly because i don't have the CSS code. I need a stackblitz for an in-depth analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have CSS `pointer-events: none;` that makes button can't click